# Could not open lock file /var/lock/aptitude No such file or directory

Tags: server, apt, aptitude

For all those who installed aptitude to easily search through apt on ubuntu 11+, upon upgrading to 11.10 I am now receiving this error.

```
[ ERR] Reading state information
E: Could not open lock file /var/lock/aptitude - open (2: No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix this:

```
sudo mkdir /run/lock
```

Aptitude should now run without issue.

Comment: /var/lock is just a symlink to /run/lock
edit the above solution to fit your needs but this should work for 99% of the users.

Comment: I did answer my own question - because I knew the answer and wanted it to be available for anyone in the community who might not.